# Passing macros with coverity exe files while using them through cmd

Tags: macros, coverity

I am new to Coverity,I am using it from the command prompt with it's .exe files.So I want to pass specific macros in coverity cov-build.exe so that those macros will be implemented when cov-emit.exe(when it is called by cov-build.exe) is parsing the .c files.Till now I have tried the below stated configurations.

```
code-build.exe Intermediate_folder --delete-stale-tus --preprocessor-first --return-emit-failure "My_bat_file" -- -D My_macro_name=my_macro_body
```

So any help will be much be appreciated.I am stuck on this.

Thanks and regards,
Newbie_in

Answer (score 0):

cov-build wraps your existing build command, monitors it and spawns parallel compiler invocations in order to understand your code. These parallel compiler invocations will see the same command line being passed to your own compiler.

So if you want this define to take effect for your compiler as well as Coverity's then you should simply just add it to your build the way you would normally and Coverity will see it.

If you want to add a define that only Coverity's compiler can see, this is best done with  within the config for your compiler.

You can either edit the config directly (add

```
<append_arg>-Dmy_macro_name=my_macro_body</append_arg>
```

after the `<begin_command_line_config>` line), or re-configure using `--xml-option`.

For example, if you're using the shortcut gcc config this would look like this:

```
$ cov-configure --gcc --xml-option=append_arg>-Dmy_macro_name=my_macro_body.
```

I noticed you're using `--preprocess-first` on the cov-build command line - I recommend against this, as it destroys XREFs making it much more difficult to browse defect information, as well as makes the analysis unable to find some defects (i.e. ones that are due to macros). `--preprocess-next` behaves like `--preprocess-first` and will only fire if the initial compilation attempt fails, so if you're using `--preprocess-first` to work around compilation issues, I strongly recommend using --preprocess-next instead.

If you do have compilation issues, it's always good to report them (along with a reproducer) to Coverity support so that they can be fixed in future releases.

Comment: Hi,  Thank you very much for the reply.I am using armcc compiler.I had tried "cov-configure --compiler armcc --comtype <location of armcc.exe> -- -Dmy_macro=my_macro_body."But this fails to include the macro along with cov-emit, which ends up parsing some code,which would have been skipped if the macro had got defined in the command line with cov-emit.I will try out the --xml-option,you have recommended.Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi Caleb,was able to resolve the problem with your command line statement suggestion.Thank you very much.  Regards, Newbie_in

Comment: `$ cov-configure --compiler <location of armcc.exe> --comptype armcc -- -Dmacro`

tells cov-configure to use `-Dmacro` in its compiler probes, it doesn't add it to the cov-emit command line (`--xml-option` does that), which is why that didn't work for you. I'm glad you got your problem fixed!